# Phone number fails my regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I use this `^((\d-\d{3})|(\d{1,3}))\-\d{3}-\d{7}$` regex to validate phone numbers.

However it does not accept the following number which is valid. What is the problem? 
Could it have to do with the zeros at the end?

```
90-312-2488900
```

Comment: Seems to match the example for me...

Comment: this regexp seems to work (http://rubular.com/)

Comment: it does not match sorry

Comment: Tested on http://regexhero.net/ as well... matches.

Comment: @user2325116 maybe it is because of whitespaces at the end of your example? try to trim your phone number prior testing

Comment: can you post the code where you evaluate the expression?

Comment: @JleruOHeP Nice, I added a whitespace to the end of it on regexhero and it no longer matched. OP, definitely try [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) before applying regex

Comment: Ok thanks it because of the whitespace:)

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to remove anything accept numeric digits from the string and then count the remaining characters. That would allow people to enter thier phone number in any format they see fit. There are many ways that people like to format phone numbers. You could store the original value unchanged, and just validate the striped version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regexp seems to work properly.

Maybe the problem is in the last space in your example. Try to remove it with [string.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.trim.aspx), or add `\s*` to your regexp (or even add it between every groups of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The space at the end of your example is what is causing it to not match. Go to [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)
and type in your regex. When you try your example, it will show you what matches and what doesn't. Without the space, you are good to go. As JleruOHep recommended, try trimming the string, or allow whitespace in your regex.

[Here is your phone number without whitespace at the end.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%28%28%5Cd-%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%7C%28%5Cd%7B1,3%7D%29%29%5C-%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B7%7D%24&input=90-312-2488900)

[And with whitespace.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%28%28%5Cd-%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%7C%28%5Cd%7B1,3%7D%29%29%5C-%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B7%7D%24&input=90-312-2488900%20)

The yellow highlight is what matches.